# I am facing some problem to load content of text file using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have tried a lot but nothing found any help.Please help me..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" id="nav1">Link1</a>|| <a href="#" id="nav2">Link2</a>
    <div id="target">&nbsp</div>
    <br clear="all" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {    
                $('#nav1').click(function() {
                    $('#target').load('home.txt');
                });
                $('#nav2').click(function() {
                    $('#target').load('link.txt');
                });
            )
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

please help me. I want to get the txt file when i click on the link1 and link2

Comment: Anyone know about it ..

Comment: what error you are getting in console ?

Comment: @Ashvin777 There is not any error in console

Comment: Seems your question is already answered. You made a small mistake to add your script code inside the external script tag. Try the solution provided by Aswin

Comment: @Ashvin777 basically i want to get the relative txt file when i click on the relative link, but when i clicked nothing is shown on the screen..

Comment: @Ashvin777 whats the small mistake is in my code

Comment: **Danger**: jQuery 1.10 is beyond end of life, it does not receive security updates, it has known security flaws. Do not use it. Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: @Quentin can you tell me what is the supported version of jquery beside 1.10

Answer (score 2):

The [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) tag cannot have the src attribute and a body, you need to use separate script tags.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nav1').click(function () {
            $('#target').load('home.txt');
        });
        $('#nav2').click(function () {
            $('#target').load('link.txt');
        });
    });
</script>
```

> This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; this can be
>   used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a
>   document. script elements with an src attribute specified should not
>   have a script embedded within its tags.

Comment: Aswin Kumar can you tell me solution what i have to do right now

Comment: @FameFamous You wrapped your script in `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"> ..your code..</script>`, you should wrap it in seperate `<script>` tag. The same is done in this answer.

Comment: @Aswin Kumar can you tell me the best solution or anny error in my code

Comment: Check the diffs in your code and in this solution you will understand. Otherwise just replace this part in your code.

Comment: still it is not working , i have separated the script tag @Aswin Kumar

Comment: @FameFamous Check if the console has any errors and post them

Comment: @AswinKumar man it is not still working. what is error in my code? please be more specific

Comment: @AswinKumar Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) it is error in console and my code is

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="target">&nbsp</div>
<br clear="all" />

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

 
 $('#nav1').click(function() {
  $('#target').load('home.txt');
 });
 $('#nav2').click(function() {
  $('#target').load('link.txt');
 });

)}; 
</script>
<a href="#" id="nav1">Link1</a>|| <a href="#" id="nav2">Link2</a>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @AswinKumar run my code first at your end then give me better solution . I shall be really thankfull to you for this action

Comment: @FameFamous change from `load('link.txt'); }); )};` to `load('link.txt'); }); });`

Comment: @AswinKumar not working man..

Comment: @AswinKumar kindly run my to your own end then give me help.

Comment: @AswinKumar ho to get answer at jsfiffle.net

Comment: @AswinKumar   where are you man??